# How after begin Text Node in DOM

Tags: javascript, dom

According to the documentation https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML
the **insertAdjacentElement** function can only add an element object,
and the **insertAdjacentText** function can only add the primitive data type "tex".

Example of successful code execution:

```js
const app = document.getElementById("app");

// Successfully add the element to the beginning of the app container
const div = document.createElement("div");
app.insertAdjacentElement("afterbegin", div);

// Successfully add the primitve text to the beginning of the app container
app.insertAdjacentElement("afterbegin", "...other text...");
```

But when I want to add a Text object, then of course an error is displayed, since insertAdjacentElement only supports Element object, example:

```js
const app = document.getElementById("app");

const text = document.createTextNode("123");
app.insertAdjacentElement("afterbegin", text ); // Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'insertAdjacentElement' on 'Element': parameter 2 is not of type 'Element'.
```

Specify, please, you can add a Text object as quickly as possible in speed (namely document.createTextNode ("123"), **PRIMARY TEXT DOES NOT FIT !!!** or NOT document.createTextNode ("123")**.data**)
to the beginning of the app container?

P.S.
insertAdjacentText and insertAdjacentHTML are NOT the same as you need to add the Text object!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly what you are trying to achieve, then you can do it using:

```
parentNode.insertBefore(newNode, parentNode.childNodes[0]);
```

---

**Working Example:**

```js
const app = document.getElementsByClassName('app')[0];

const text = document.createTextNode('123');
app.insertBefore(text, app.childNodes[0]);
```

```html
<div class="app">

  <h2>My App</h2>

</div>
```